How to display result depending on the radio button choice?
I'm working on an Android Studio activity in which I have to calculate area and perimeter. I used intent to pass and access variables that will be used in another activity where the computations will happen. What I want to happen is that when the user chooses or selects either the Perimeter or the Area radio buttons, the code with the specified calculations should run. The problem is that when I run my code, nothing displays following the user input. We are required to use view Binding in this activity so I'm not sure how I can use the isChecked() or isSelected() functions.
MainActivity.kt: (first activity)
val radioGrp = binding.radioGroup.text
val radioBtn1 = binding.radioButton1.text
val radioBtn2 = binding.radioButton2.text
val length = binding.edtTxtLength.text.toString()
val width = binding.edtTxtWidth.text.toString()

intent.putExtra("rGroup", radioGrp)
intent.putExtra("Btn1", radioBtn1)
intent.putExtra("Btn2", radioBtn2)
intent.putExtra("Length", length)
intent.putExtra("Width", width)

Activity.kt: (second activity)
val getRGroup = intent.getStringExtra("rGroup")
val getRBtn1 = intent.getStringExtra("Btn1")
val getRBtn2 = intent.getStringExtra("Btn2")
val getLength = intent.getStringExtra("Length")
val getWidth = intent.getStringExtra("Width")
val Area = getLength*getWidth
val Perimeter = 2*(getLength+getWidth)

if(getRGroup == getRBtn1)
{
    binding.textArea.text = buildString{
       append("Perimeter\n\n")
       append("Answer: $Perimeter")
    }   
}
else if (getRGroup == getRBtn2)
{
    binding.textArea.text = buildString{
       append("Area\n\n")
       append("Answer: $Area")
    }  
}

It should do the perimeter calculation based on the conditional statement if the user selects the radio button designated for it, and the same goes for the area calculation.

The first three extras you are creating and reading are not useful information for the second activity, so you can remove those. You are just passing along the text labels of those elements, not the user input.
Instead, you should use isChecked to determine which one is checked, and pass that along instead.
var selectedButton = 0
if (binding.btn1.isChecked) {
    selectedButton = 1
} else if (binding.btn2.isChecked) {
    selectedButton = 2
} 

//..

intent.putExtra("selectedButton", selectedButton)

Then in the second activity, you can use getIntExtra("selectedButton") to get the selected button value, which will either be 1 or 2, assuming at one of the radio buttons was selected.
For the length and width, you should be passing Ints as well, not Strings. You can call toIntOrNull() ?: 0 after calling toString() on those EditTexts to convert from Strings to numbers.
